# Azure App Registrations Sign-on URL

Tags: azure, registration, azure-resource-manager

I am registering an app with Azure, so that I can automate deployments with Ansible. Ansible is not a Web App (but a simple command line tool), but on an app registration it asks to fill in a mandatory field `Sign-on URL`. The description it gives is `The URL where user can sign in and use your app.` But once again, there is no URL and no Web App.

I could not find another way to register an app and it seems that this is the recommended way from the Ansible side. [Ansible docs on Azure](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/guide_azure.html) are linking to [App registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) in Azure.

So for now, I have entered a random URL there, but if it is not needed, then why Microsoft are enforcing it on us?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to change the Application type from Web App to a Native App in the dropdown above Sign-on URL.

Comment: Then it asks for a `Redirect URI` which doesn't mean anything either

Comment: For native apps, please use the following Redirect URI: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`.

Comment: Idk what this URI is meant to be, but I am not using `oauth 2.0` or any such authentication mechanism. I am using a command line tool that sends some requests to the Azure Management Portal API and creates/modifies/deletes some resources like a Virtual Machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is a required field during app registration is that during the vast majority of cases, the app in question is actually an app that people associate with a URL and can sign in to.

If you don't need the Sign-on URL, then you can put whatever value you'd like. I recommend a unique URL that is unlikely to collide with other people's apps or other apps in your organization.

You can also always do the app registration programmatically (since it look like scripting is your scenario anyway), using Azure AD PowerShell's `New-AzureADApplication` (followed by `New-AzureADServicePrincipal`).

Answer (score 1):

> Sign-On URL: For "Web app / API" applications, provide the base URL of your app. For example, http://localhost:31544 might be the URL for a web app running on your local machine. Users would use this URL to sign in to a web client application.

That's because you register an web app/API. The type of application register will add to the [access panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-access-panel-introduction) and the users could login the app through access panel via the **Sign-on URL** you config it when you register the app.

As Gaurav Mantri suggested, if you were not developing web app you should register an **native app** instead of **web app**.

More info about Azure app register, you can refer the document below:

[Integrating applications with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications)

[Register your client application with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad)

Comment: Yes, but if I try to register a native app, then it asks for a `Redirect URI`, so exactly the same issue, but a different URI name

Comment: For the redirect URI is used for **Native Application** to return the tokens. If you were not request the token, would you mind sharing the reason you register the app on Azure portal? If you doesn't need it, you can write any  validate URI to complete the register

Comment: I am registering an app, so that I can generate a key for the Ansible automation scripts that create vms on Azure and stuff like that. So I get a key, I add it to my script and I run it from a command line. After the script finishes, that's it. I don't need any tokens. Maybe I don't fully understand the idea of these tokens, but it works now with a random URI I entered

Comment: Yes, I just put a random valid URI, but it is strange that it is compulsory, while I don't really need it

Comment: The apps register on Azure is used to interact with Azure Active Directory. And Azure AD supports protocols like OpenID connect, OAuth 2.0. And it is very common to provide the **redirect_urI** for using these protocols. That's reason I guess why users required to provide it when register an app.

Comment: And you mentioned provided the secret, it may use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) of OAuth2.0 which do doesn't require the `redirect_uri`. If you have any idea or feedback about Azure Active Directory, you can submit it from [this site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).